# How to know if a video from <iframe> is playing (youtube AND vimeo)

Tags: javascript, html

I have an iframe of youtube / vimeo content and I would know if the video is playing when my function is executed.

Actually, when someone click on an image, my code set the right video corresponding at this image in the iframe. and i have a button which pause and hide my iframe

I found this with youtube API: `getPlayerState()` ,
and `getPaused()` from vimeo API.

I don't want to use click event, I would like to be able to know the pauseState at everytime !

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=fr
https://developer.vimeo.com/player/sdk/reference#events-for-text-tracks

```html
<iframe id="player" class="center" width="560" height="315" src="" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
```

```
function loadVideo(id) {
    var videoPlayer = document.getElementById('videoPlayer');


    var player = document.getElementById('player');
    var url = player.src;

    switch (id) {
        case 1:
            url = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/n1tswFfg-Ig?enablejsapi=1";
            break ;

        case 2:
            url = "https://player.vimeo.com/video/237596019?api=1";
            break ;
                default:
            callPlayer("pauseVideo");
            break ;




function callPlayer(func, args) {
    var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
    for (var i = 0; i < iframes.length; ++i) {
        if (iframes[i]) {
            var src = iframes[i].getAttribute('src');
            if (src) {
                if (src.indexOf('youtube.com/embed') != -1) {
                    var player = new YT.Player(iframes[i], {});
                    //2 lines below doesn't work
                        var value = player.getPlayerState();
                    alert('value');
                    iframes[i].contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify({
                        'event': 'command',
                        'func': func,
                        'args': args || []
                    }), "*");
                }
                if (src.indexOf('player.vimeo.com/video') != -1) {
                    var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframes[i]);
                    switch (func) {
                        case 'pauseVideo':
                            //always show 'false', never 'true'
                                        if (player.getPaused() == true ) {
                                alert('true');
                            }else {
                                alert('false');
                            }

                            player.pause();
                            break ;
                        default:
                            break ;
                 }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i use alert to know if something is working, and with this code, the youtube alert does not work , and the vimeo alert always show 'false'.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have a look at the [youtube player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference), the player state changes to `playing`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the issue can be related to the use of the same `iframe`, which ends up messing up the functions of each type of video. In this way, a solution would be to use more than one iframe that would be displayed or hidden as needed.

Another problem that has been reported is that starting the YouTube video directly through `<iframe>` does not end up activating the listening functions. So, the ideal is to follow as recommended in the [YouTube Player API documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) and start the video with a `<div>`, so that `.getPlayerState()` and other methods work well.

```js
// Buttons to switch videos
function changeVideo (btn) {
  if (btn.classList.contains("active")) {
    return;
  }
  document.querySelector('.buttons .active').classList.remove('active');
  document.querySelector('.video .active').classList.remove('active');

  document.querySelector("." + btn.dataset.video + "-video").classList.add('active');
  btn.classList.add('active');
}

// YouTube starter
let youtubePlayer;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  youtubeVideo = new YT.Player('youtubePlayer', {
    height: '315',
    width: '560',
    videoId: 'tgbNymZ7vqY'
  });
}

// YouTube - check if it's paused
function checkYoutubePaused() {
  let state = youtubeVideo.getPlayerState();
  if (state <= 0 || state == 2 || state == 5) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

// Vimeo starter
const vimeoIframe = document.querySelector('.vimeo-video');
const vimeoPlayer = new Vimeo.Player(vimeoIframe);

// Vimeo - check if it's paused
async function checkVimeoPaused() {
  let state;
  await vimeoPlayer.getPaused().then(function(paused) {
    state = paused;
  });
  return state;
}

// My Function
async function myFunction() {
  
  vimeoState = await checkVimeoPaused();
  
  let youtubePaused = checkYoutubePaused() ? "PAUSED" : "RUNNING";
  let vimeoPaused = vimeoState ? "PAUSED" : "RUNNING";

  alert("Youtube Video is " +  youtubePaused + "\n" + "Vimeo Video is " + vimeoPaused);
  
}
```

```css
.youtube-video {
  display: none;
}
.vimeo-video {
  display: none;
}
.video .active {
  display: inline; 
}
.buttons .active {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #333333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>

<div class="video">
 
  <div id="youtubePlayer" class="youtube-video active"></div>   
  <iframe class="vimeo-video" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/120680495" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</div>  

<div>
  
  <span class="buttons">
    <button data-video="youtube" class="active" onclick="changeVideo(this)">Youtube Video</button>
    <button data-video="vimeo" onclick="changeVideo(this)">Vimeo Video</button>
  </span>
  
  <span>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Run My Function</button>
  </span>
 
</div>
```